# How are multiple sentences printed in Java using Scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to print multiple sentences (each having more than one word) in Java but I am getting a run time error even after using `.nextLine()`. Below is my code, could someone point out what am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.*;
class GFG
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt(); //t>1
        for(int p=1; p<=t; p++)
        {
            sc.nextLine();
            String s = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}   // Input-
    // 2
    // HOW ARE YOU
    // GOD IS ONE
    // Output-
    // HOW ARE YOU -(followed by run time error)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line in the for-loop: `sc.nextLine()` reads a line from the in stream and discards it (the return value is not placed into any variable). In your code, you read two lines in every iteration (4 for the provided input) while there are only 2 lines of input. Therefore you need to remove this line (the first `sc.nextLine()`).

As a side note, when I tried to run the program it just waited for more lines and did not throw a runtime error (also in case you encountered one it's better to post the exception itself).

Comment: If this question helped you and resolved your issue, please mark it as the solution when you can @SamyakSrivastava